# How to write oracle sql query for remaining totals

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following data set returned by query is following, i am displaying some rows down below, but actual data returned is over 500k rows.

```
Date         | amount
01-01-2010   | 200
01-02-2010   | 50
01-03-2010   | 400
01-04-2010   | 50
01-05-2010   | 0
01-06-2010   | 0
01-07-2010   | 100
```

I would like query to return **Remaining Amount** column something like this:

```
Date         | amount   | Remaining
01-01-2010   | 200      | 600
01-02-2010   | 50       | 550
01-03-2010   | 400      | 150
01-04-2010   | 50       | 100
01-05-2010   | 0        | 100
01-06-2010   | 0        | 100
01-07-2010   | 100      | 0
```

*Remaining Amount* starts with sum of total amount, which is sum of all records amount column.

Comment: Where does the `remaining` beginning value come from, the `sum`?

Comment: remaining value starts with sum of total amount

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use oracle analytic functions

```
SELECT DATE,
   AMOUNT,
   (SUM (AMOUNT) OVER ()) - (SUM (AMOUNT) OVER (ORDER BY DATE))
      AS REMAINING
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the [Windowing Clause](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) to avoid the `SUM(AMOUNT) - (...)`:

```
SELECT dt, AMOUNT,
   nvl(sum(amount) over 
      (order by dt desc rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)
   , 0) as REMAINING
FROM yourtable
order by dt
```

Using the analytic functions should give better performance than correlated subquery, because table is scanned only once.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one approach using a correlated subquery with `coalesce`:

```
select y.dt,
  y.amount,
  coalesce((select sum(amount)
   from yourtable y2
   where y2.dt > y.dt),0) as remaining
from yourtable y
order by y.dt
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef49fd/5)

Comment: Using a window function will be much faster than the co-related sub-query